# Clustered/stacked point popup

Tags: popup, geoserver, getfeatureinfo

Maybe my question is stupid or what, as I am pretty new to Geoserver.
Why does my custom content.ftl popup template work flawlessly for line-based layers and point-based layers in GeoServer, but when I apply clustering or point stacking in the styling of a layer, the default popup style is used instead of my custom template? What is causing this behavior?
Note: I am using React Leaflet version 4 and displaying the layers using WMSTileLayer.
Thank you

What I did was creating a file called **content.ftl** which contains the custom popup content in `/data_dir/workspace/workspace_name/layer_name/`.

Comment: because clustering creates a "new" temporary layer?

Comment: Thanks @IanTurton, I created a folder called "templates" in  "/data_dir" and I got it working, which is a bit hacky, but the tooltip of the other layers provided by Geoserver by default throw an error when I click on them.